# What happens when I pass access_key and secret_key to my ec2 instance via cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

What exactly happens when I pass secret_key and access_key to my ec2 instance in the USER DATA section via cloudformation template and how is it different from creating an instance without it.

So I am trying below template and it creates the resources fine. But I am not able to login using the user created into the ec2 instance. I know I must be doing some blunder here.

```
    "Resources":{
    "myuser" : {
   "Type" : "AWS::IAM::User",
   "Properties" : {
   "UserName":"naxi143",
      "Path" : "/",
      "LoginProfile" : {
         "Password" : "143@Naxi143"
      }
      }
    },
      "myaccesskey" : {
   "Type" : "AWS::IAM::AccessKey",
   "Properties" : {
      "UserName" : { "Ref" : "myuser" }
   }
},
    "WebServerGroup" : {
          "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
          "Properties" : {
            "VPCZoneIdentifier" : { "Ref" : "Subnets" },  
            "LaunchConfigurationName" : { "Ref" : "LaunchConfig" },
            "MinSize" : "1",
            "MaxSize" : "1"
            }
      },
    "LaunchConfig" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
      "Properties" : {
        "ImageId" :"ami-40142d25",
        "SecurityGroups" : { "Ref" : "WebServerSecurityGroup" },
        "InstanceType" : { "Ref" : "InstanceType" }, "UserData" : {
         "Fn::Base64" : {
            "Fn::Join" : [
               "", [
                  "ACCESS_KEY=", {
                     "Ref" : "myaccesskey"
                  },
                  "&",
                  "SECRET_KEY=",
                  {
                     "Fn::GetAtt" : [
                        "myaccesskey",
                        "SecretAccessKey"
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            ]
         }
        }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: In this template: nothing. Second, it's a bad idea to put your access and secret keys in the templates. Third, the IAM user is NOT what you use to ssh into the machine. If you use Amazon's AMI, the login user name is: ec2-user

Comment: If you're trying to provide permissions to the EC2 instances in an Auto Scaling Group then you need to create an appropriate IAM role and an Instance Profile, and then indicate that Instance Profile in the launch config via IamInstanceProfile.

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 I understand that IAM user is not supposed to be used for SSH. I was going through aws docs and got stuck on this line -  

"You can also pass the AWS access key and secret key to an EC2 instance or Auto Scaling group defined in the template. "

The code above  for user data is directly copied from there.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-iam.html#scenario-iam-accesskey

Comment: What are you trying to do? As @jarmod mentioned, if you are looking to access AWS services, you need to attach an IAM role to the instance. User data is used to bootstrap your EC2 instance (example: adding it to domain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IAM users are for access the AWS Console and the access keys are for accessing the  APIs. To SSH into the instance (or RDP for windows) you need to create a ssh key pair (in the Ec2 console) and then you can attached this key to the instance.

The user data can be use in two ways. The first is more common in my experience

1. It can be a shell script that is execute only the very first time the instance is booted. You can use this to install software and perform other actions at boot.
2. User data can be cloud-init directives (I think amazon linux only).
3. You can put any configuration data you want in user data and then access it via 169.254.169.169/user-data/latest from your application.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. My confusion here is what exactly does the user data in above section does. Can you please tell me that as well.  :-)